# ng-leave should animate based on current event

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have an app with a bunch of tabs implemented using ngroute.

How would you make the tabs animate the tab switch for specific links and not animate for all other links. (all the links in question cause a route change)

I use `Angular 1.2.x`

**More information (only if you didn't understand my question)**

When I switch tabs using certain, specific, links I'd like the previous tab to animate out and the new one to animate in.

When I use another set of links, I expect the tabs to switch without navigation at all.

My problem - The "leaving" tab is not dependent on the current click event that caused the route change so I don't know how to enable or disable its behaviour based on the current click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css class like:

```
.animated-render.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity:1;
}
.animated-render.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity:0;
}
```

And then apply `.animated-render` class to specific element.

Comment: but applying a class to a specific element would cause the entering element to have that class and the leaving one would be unchanged...